# Install Modx 1.0.5 Error at WAMP

Tags: php, installation, modx, modx-evolution

I try to install modx 1.0.5 on my WAMP server with this specification

1. PHP v5.2.11
2. MySQL v5.5.8
3. OS Win 7

and this is the error i get

```
Install results

Setup will now attempt to setup the database:

Creating connection to the database: OK!

Selecting database `modx105`: OK!

Checking table prefix `modx_`: OK!

Creating database tables: Database Alerts!

MODx setup couldn't install/alter some tables inside the selected database.

The following errors had occurred during installation

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM COMMENT='Contains data about active users.'' at line 9 during the execution of SQL statement CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `modx_active_users` ( `internalKey` int(9) NOT NULL default '0', `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '', `lasthit` int(20) NOT NULL default '0', `id` int(10) default NULL, `action` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '', `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '', PRIMARY KEY (`internalKey`) ) TYPE=MyISAM COMMENT='Contains data about active users.'.
```

i didn't put all the information error, since its too long.

Is seems strange for me, since my friend install this on XAMPP server and the install run correctly. Is there maybe some configuration of my WAMP server make this installation failure?

Since my WAMP Configuration is not much change except enable rewriteEngine in Apache and add PHP 5.2.11 version

Thank you in advance

Comment: BTW, MODx Revolution is *so* much better than the legacy one

Comment: @Phil Yes modx Revo is better. but most hosting in indonesia still run using PHP 5.2.2 (o.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick search, `TYPE` is no longer supported and hasn't been for a very long time. It should be `ENGINE=MyISAM`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-create-table.html

Why this is part of the installer is yet to be determined.

### Update

I've filed a bug [#4156](http://bugs.modx.com/issues/4156)

You can try this workaround in the meantime - http://modxcms.com/forums/index.php?topic=60964.new;topicseen#new

Comment: @GusDe Weird thing was, the same bug had been filed, fixed and closed for Revolution. You'd think they'd do both code bases